How would a culture living in an extremely vertical environment deal with dead bodies?
My world has a nation known as Volantes, which is, as the title suggests, extremely vertical. It consists of millions of floating islands in a column, held aloft by a stone called gravitite, which undoes the affects of gravity, and weakly follows the flow of magic upwards. Land is extremely fertile but limited, and populations live in very dense areas, making burial not very realistic besides a mass grave. Cremation is also not feasible, as the smoke would cloud those living on higher islands. In low populations, dealing with corpses can be done by creating a sort of sarcophagus and floating it up until it's eventually pushed into the area surrounding Volantes and eventually falls apart, but gravitite is limited, just as land is, so that doesn't work when populations are much higher. What are ways these bodies could be dealt with that would minimize pollution and resource use?
Magic does exist, but can only more easily recreate the things we already have in the real world, making it not very relevant for the question.

This is borderline brain storm and or story driven. Because for example people place bodies on the Ganges which flows through very densely populated areas. That is for religious /historical people may cremate and damn the consequences cause that's the proper way.  It is up to your story as to the proper way.

What happens to all other organic waste?  What happens to water run-off and associated soil erosion?  (Big problem for all "floating island" worlds is how they last any significant amount of time.)  Without knowing how the big issues of waste and loss work, we can't comment on the relatively tiny volume of dead human(?) bodies.

Why not something like a catapult?

@Dragongeek You must mean a trebuchet.

You're missing that the higher in the atmosphere, the stronger is the wind there. Any smoke would just be blown off by the winds, likely even before it would reach the closest island above the bonfire. Yet, burning should really not be done for other reasons already explained in the answers.

Let the dead go the way of all poop.

It might be wise of you to think of the everyday practicalities of food/water/waste before trying to frame death without context. Are there animals/birds/microorganisms/plants - how do they all survive and die in your world? Any cultural-based practice should be in all that context.

Observe what they do in extremely dense city-states, namely Hong Kong and Singapore: your options are cremation and storing the ashes in a cubby in a high-rise (columbarium), or shipping the body elsewhere.

"Cremation is also not feasible, as the smoke would cloud those living on higher islands" - no, not really. Unless there is an extreme event causing a huge death toll, cremation would be such a rare event compared to all other cases where something needs to be burned (for heating, cooking, industry), that its smoke would be completely negligible.

Millions of floating islands in a column? Even if the islands were as close to each other as floors of a building, less than the bottom 5% would be inhabitable, most of the rest would be in outer space.

I have two suggestions, both inspired by real-world practice in India, which is very densely populated, if not especially vertical.
Sticky-Out Bits of Silence
Parsis dispose of the bodies of the dead on 'Towers of Silence'; they put bodies on top of towers for the birds to eat, thereby avoiding creating pollution. Having long gantries of some sort sticking out the sides of your floating rocks would serve the same purpose. You would probably want to put some sort of roof or shelter over the platform so the people living above couldn't actually see what was going on, of course.
Cremation
You said in your question that cremation was infeasible due to the smoke being a nuisance for those above. Frame challenge: does that matter? In India it is common for cremations to be performed with open fires in built-up areas, and the remains - which aren't neat little piles of ashes like a crematorium produces - are cast into the river, where people wash, get drinking water etc. This water is considered spiritually enhanced, rather than dirtied. People just put up with the smoke and general unpleasantness - if they want to live in a nicer neighbourhood, then that's their prerogative. Forcing cremations to be carried out elsewhere wouldn't even be considered!

Compost them
You have to keep the bodies there, because otherwise you are throwing all the elements they contain away.  The land won't remain fertile for long if it's endlessly drained of nutrients that get thrown away.
Even on Earth, there are practices that can accelerate the process.

Throw them over the edge?
Really scratching my head on this one, but I don't see any stated reason why you wouldn't just dump the bodies overboard? Your islands either seem to be floating over some sort of void or a landmass they don't interact with. In this situation I see no reason why your populace wouldn't just throw their corpses and general waste over the edge to let gravity carry away the detritus to a magical place known as "Not our problem".
I mean I’m sure someone is going to stand on a pedestal and give a speech on the nobleness of life, the sanctity of death and how all the people involved in tossing the deceased off the island are really good people. Pretty sure the cadaver would then be launched clear of the air zone of the island stack with some sort of catapult, ballista or magical cannon – at which point the assembled mourners would disperse to go find some brunch.
The only reason I could think of that the dead would not be disposed of in this manner is that on a floating island connected to neither land nor ocean, the islands are going to fast be drained of both organic and inorganic nutrients – at which point you may need to keep the departed around as a dietary supplement.

Sky Burial
If you have flying scavengers like vultures this traditional Tibet burial custom would be a fit. Bodies are left in a more isolated, ritual location to decompose and be scavenged by birds, returning the deceased to nature.

You might mention that in Tibet this practice is encouraged by the lack of firewood for cremation (above treeline) and the lack of soil for burial (exposed bedrock)

The corpse can be returned to nature in the form of nutrients for other organisms, like in this case:

Even the most environmentally friendly burials have drawbacks. Ground burial takes up precious real estate. Cremation endangers crematoria workers who can breathe in poisonous fumes. But a new burial method, called “promession,” solves the problems of both space and pollution. This technique, Wired reports, involves dipping a body into liquid nitrogen, vibrating it into thousands of tiny pieces and freeze-drying the resulting powder. Buried in the ground, in a few short months, the powder will turn into human fertilizer, helping flowers or trees to grow.

Since you state

Magic does exist, but can only more easily recreate the things we already have in the real world

getting liquid nitrogen is not an issue.

Sidenote: While Promession sounds pretty much as being possible, Wikipedia suggests that this is still debatable (while not providing any details to the "why"). The company pursuing to establish the process as new form of burial went bankrupt in 2015. Until now, no such "Promator" device was built. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promession It would be also fairly cost/energy intensive to provide the cryogen (magic amends ofc). A body is not just "dipped" but has to be "drowned" in a tank for quite a while before being thoroughly frozen. It seems to be still a bit of Sci-fi as of today.

why not just throw them into a wood chipper?

@ths so you've seen Fargo too?

What's the climate like?  In warm locations with lack of burial space it's pretty common for people to have built particular styles of mausoleum.  They include sealable niches in an exterior wall, and then also usually a permanent storage area.
The tradition is generally to place the corpse in the niche for a year and a day or some such dramatic-sounding length of time.  The main purpose is to ensure that the corpse stays in through the requisite hot season.  Being a big, stone structure out in the scorching hot sun, the interior of the niches gets hot enough to cremate the body, although slowly.  This way there is no smoke and particulates going everywhere.  By the time the niche is unsealed to move everything to permanent storage, there's usually very little left but bones and dust.  And depending on the amount of heat, even the bones can be seriously degraded.
Wealthier families often have private facilities and move the bones down to a crypt or ossuary.  The poorer people can pay to be placed in a public facility.  These are often built into the cemetery wall, which is constructed with a vault underneath and a hole at the back.  After the requisite period the chamber can be re-used by the simple expedient of opening the door and sweeping whatever is left inside to the rear, where it falls into the vault for permanent storage.
In colder areas with lack of land, similar things are often done with regular graveyards.  You use gravesites in rotation so the flesh has time to decay, and then when a fresh body needs the grave you dig up the old bones and move them to more compact storage.  Similar to how, in Hamlet, Yorick ended up getting moved to make space for Ophelia.

Topmost Fire Temple Island / Dedicated Graveyard Islands
If your chain of islands has a topmost one and if it is possible to carry dead bodies up there, they might have built a temple specifically for cremation the bodies at this place.
Since you did not mention any kind of other environment, like a planet, I would also suggest paying attention to the "sustainable ecosystem" idea. If all bodies are burned, those islands will be "dried out" (deprived of nutritions) over time.
Maybe they even use a few of the islands as dedicated graveyards to produce compost? If having millions of islands, maybe a few hundred of those are sufficient already.

Most of the compounds lost when burning the bodies would also be lost during natural decomposition. There has to be some way for those to return to the islands regardless. And there has to be something providing the gravity that the magic mineral holds things up against, so the question is how far down and how inhospitable is the surface. Are they floating over a terrestrial planet? Or is this more like "The Integral Trees", by Larry Niven...

@Perkins: That should go as comment below the question. I cannot answer that.

Magic Burial in Gemstones
Since magic is in place, you might consider some special case for transforming dead bodies into glowing/shiny crystal gems? The bereaved can put them on their night table/house shrine or wear them as jewels in necklaces or rings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Silence
Basically, burry it in the sky, on dedicated towers.

Frame Challenge: Population Density can never be high enough for this to become an actual problem.

Land is extremely fertile but limited, and populations live in very dense areas, making burial not very realistic besides a mass grave.

When you look at dense cities full of high rises packed with 1000s of people, have you ever considered how much land those people are actually using up?  Not just the square footage of their apartments, but all of the collective countryside it takes to feed that person: room for roads, a place of business, mines, and all of the manufacturing facilities they get their goods from, they are all prerequisites for a person to live and they must all fit on your islands.
Most of your landscape will be farmland.  There is no way around this.  Even in areas of artificially high fertility, long growing seasons that allow succession planting, ubiquitous herbicide and pesticide use, and crops that are chosen for their high caloric density, you need about 1/2 and acre of farmland per person. Plus there has to be whatever forests, mines, reservoirs, and other sources of raw materials they rely on which means you can never get a sum of exploited landmass to less than about 1 acre per person, though realistically this number is closer to 3 acres.
That is about 4000-12000 square meters per person.  If you don't have at least this, then your civilization will implode, and people with starve or kill each other until their populations are reduced to fit this need.
That said, bodies do not take very much to get rid of.  You could simply bury them in your feed or fallow fields so that they break down and become fertilizer.  You could turn old depleted mines or quarries into catacombes. You could actually burn the bodies just fine in times of plague because there will be plenty of open fields with lots of space for the smoke to spread over: just use the land of one of the farmers who didn't make it so no one has to smell it.
Or... if resources are scarce enough, you could use the bodies.  Nearly the entire human body can be turned into useful things like food, leather, bone meal, etc.
